# Can I use "outnumber" interchangeably with "exceed"?

Tags: word-choice

In this sentence:

> The drop in overseas visitors in the first three quarters of this year
>   exceeded the drop in mainland Chinese tourists.

Is it incorrect to use "outnumber" in place of "exceed"?

Comment: Why do you think outnumber is wrong?

Comment: The sentence is referring to a single drop (of overseas visitors) against another single drop (of mainland Chinese tourists). It will be incongruous to many that a single example of something can "outnumber" a single example of another thing. Even if you allow that *drop* can be treated as a collective here, you have a further difficulty of expressing a negative value as "outnumbering" another negative value, which is uncommon.

Comment: And note that the two words are not interchangeable.  You would not say "the drop in visitors *outnumbered* 7%", even though "the drop in visitors *exceeded* 7%" is reasonably idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant formulation that avoids your problem could be:

> In the first three quarters of this year the number of overseas visitors fell by more than the number of mainland Chinese tourists.

But back to your question of *exceed* versus *outnumber*. As alluded to by `choster` in the comment, *outnumber* requires the reference word to be a countable entity. E.g.:

> Visitors from overseas outnumbered those from mainland China.

*Visitors* is countable. The *drop in visitors* however, though measurable, is *not* countable.

*Exceed*, in its meaning 2 in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exceed), allows a comparison of anything that is at least conceptually measurable, though not necessarily countable. E.g.,

> Peter's success exceeded his father's expectations.

While you can measure success, you can't count it.

*Visitors*, while countable, are not measurable. You can measure all kinds of *attributes* of visitors (such as visitor spending, the average age of visitors, etc), but not  *visitors* themselves. Thus, to make *exceed* work in the way intended by the OP, one could refer to the *number of visitors*, which is measurable:

> The number of visitors from overseas exceeded the number of tourists from mainland China.

Since *drop* is measurable but not countable, it works as a reference word for *exceed*, but not for *outnumer*. You could alter the last sentence to use the words *drop in the number of visitors*, but the whole phrase becomes very clumsy. Hence my  suggestion at the beginning.

Comment: Your explanations really make sense. Thx a lot!

Comment: @user261533 It's customary to up-vote helpful answers. After that, wait a couple of days, then give the green tick to whichever answer best answers your question. (If none do, there's no obligation to award the green tick.)